# Master Server Bind i's OK but Slave NO

Tags: ubuntu, bind, master-slave

I install two dns server (BIND 9) was the first master, the second is slave.

**In Master Server:**

The file /etc/bind/named.conf.local

> > ```
> > zone "globaltic.tk" {
> >     type master;
> >     file "/etc/bind/db.globaltic.tk";
> >     notify no;
> >     allow-transfer { 192.168.1.2; };
> > ```
> >
> > };
> >
> > ```
> >   zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
> >     type master;
> >     notify no;
> >     file "/etc/bind/db.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
> >     allow-transfer { 192.168.1.2; };
> > ```
> >
> > };

NOW THE FILE ZONE:db.globaltic.tk

> > ```
> > $TTL 604800
> > @  IN      SOA     NS1.globaltic.tk.      root.globaltic.tk. (
> >                                                     ** 1 ;serial **
> >                                                     3600 ;refresh
> >                                                     3600 ;retry
> >                                                     **2419200 ;expire**
> >                                                     3600 ;minimum TTL)
> >  @           IN      NS      NS1.globaltic.tk.
> >  @           IN      NS      NS2.globaltic.tk.
> >  @           IN      MX  10  mail.globaltic.tk.
> >  NS1         IN      A       192.168.1.1
> >  NS2         IN      A       192.168.1.2
> >  mail        IN      A       192.168.1.2
> >  www         IN      A       192.168.1.3
> > ```

**In Slave Server**
The file /etc/named.conf.local :

> > ```
> > //
> > // Do any local configuration here
> > //
> > // Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
> > // organization
> > //include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
> >
> > zone "globaltic.tk" {
> >     type slave;
> >     file "/var/cache/bind/db.globaltic.tk";
> >     masters { 192.168.1.1; };
> > ```
> >
> > };
> >
> > ```
> > zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
> >     type slave;
> >     file "/var/cache/bind/db.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
> >     masters { 192.168.1.1; };
> > ```
> >
> > };

The file /var/cache/bind/db.globaltic.tk

> > ```
> > $ORIGIN .
> > $TTL 604800     ; 1 week
> >
> > globaltic.tk            IN SOA  NS1.globaltic.tk. root.globaltic.tk. (
> >                             **2011041410 ; serial**
> >                             3600       ; refresh (1 hour)
> >                             3600       ; retry (1 hour)
> >                             **3600       ; expire (1 hour)**
> >                             3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
> >                             )
> >                     NS      NS1.globaltic.tk.
> >                     NS      NS2.globaltic.tk.
> >                     MX      10 mail.globaltic.tk.
> >
> > $ORIGIN globaltic.tk.
> > mail                    A       192.168.1.2
> > NS1                     A       192.168.1.1
> > NS2                     A       192.168.1.2
> > www                     A       192.168.1.3
> > ```

the contents of / etc / resolv.conf in the master NS1
search globaltic.tk
nameserver 192.168.1.1
the contents of / etc / resolv.conf in the Slave NS2
search globaltic.tk
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2

**the problem is:**

-the update can not be made between the master and slave, although I restart bind and reboot each server.

-when I did nslookup nslookup ns1 mail or on the Master server it works, but in the Slave it gives me this message:

> > ```
> >   ;; connection timed out; No servers Could Be Reached
> > ```

Comment: Can you use host/dig from your slave and get a good zone transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems. (1) As highlighted in your post, something got messed up with the serial numbers. The slave has a greater serial number than the master so it will not update its zone data when it receives a notify from the master. Assuming you are using the YYYYMMDDNN convention for serial numbers, update the master zone file to 2011052300. (2) You have `notify no;` set so the master won't send notifications. Remove that (in both places). After that restarting named on the master should allow the slave to start updating.

As for the timeout running `nslookup` there may be a firewall blocking access from ns2 to ns1 or you have some acls in your named.conf that you aren't showing.

Comment: the same thing, I deleted (notify no;) in the configuration.
then I change the serial in the two files (/ etc / bind / master & db.globaltic.tk in / var / cache / bind / db.globaltic.tk in Slavic). I gave the serial "1"
I even reboot both systems.
 and the same thing:-(

Comment: Is netfilter enabled on these servers? To debug you could start a packet capture on both hosts, delete `/var/cache/bind/db.globaltic.tk` on the slave and restart named on the slave.

Comment: I deleted the file (/ var / cache / bind / db.globaltic.tk). and I reboot the system (slave).
in / var / cache / bind any files. the slave has not made ​​the update, well, this whole setup I did before she walks very well on both servers, but the only change I made is the installation of the package (IRedMail the slave (NS2)) I believe that IRedMail contains some configuration netfiltrer. quesque I should do? to test the netfilter and if there is a rule give me please.

Comment: (from Slave)#telnet @ip_Master 53                                 Trying 192.168.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: # tail -f /var/log/syslog
May 24 00:32:19 NS2 named[1684]: zone globaltic.tk/IN: refresh: retry limit for master 192.168.1.1#53 exceeded (source 0.0.0.0#0)
May 24 00:32:19 NS2 named[1684]: zone globaltic.tk/IN: Transfer started.
May 24 00:32:39 NS2 named[1684]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: refresh: retry limit for master 192.168.1.1#53 exceeded (source 0.0.0.0#0)
May 24 00:32:39 NS2 named[1684]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: Transfer started.

Comment: May 24 00:32:40 NS2 named[1684]: transfer of 'globaltic.tk/IN' from 192.168.1.1#53: failed to connect: timed out
May 24 00:32:40 NS2 named[1684]: transfer of 'globaltic.tk/IN' from 192.168.1.1#53: Transfer completed: 0 messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 20.999 secs (0 bytes/sec)
May 24 00:33:00 NS2 named[1684]: transfer of '1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 192.168.1.1#53: failed to connect: timed out

Comment: ns2 cannot communicate with ns1. (1) Is ns1 listening correctly: `lsof -i | grep named`. (2) Is there a firewall on ns1: `iptables -L -v -n`.

Comment: root@NS1:~#  lsof -i | grep named
named      778     bind   20u  IPv6   3543      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
named      778     bind   21u  IPv4   3548      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
named      778     bind   22u  IPv4   3550      0t0  TCP ns1.globaltic.tk:domain (LISTEN)
named      778     bind   23u  IPv4   3582      0t0  TCP localhost:953 (LISTEN)
named      778     bind   24u  IPv6   3583      0t0  TCP localhost:953 (LISTEN)
named      778     bind  512u  IPv6   3542      0t0  UDP *:domain

Comment: >>     named      778     bind  513u  IPv4   3547      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
>>     named      778     bind  514u  IPv4   3549      0t0  UDP ns1.globaltic.tk:domain

Comment: root@NS1:~# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 116 packets, 8049 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  755 38759 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443,25,465,110,995,143,993,587,465,22
  554 33284 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Comment: icmp type 8

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1445 packets, 93218 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination